# Unhandled event loop exception in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, mercurial

I just installed maven and mercurial plugins from eclipse marketplace to my Kepler version. Now when I try to create new Google web application project I get the following error:

Message: Unhandled event loop exception
Plug-in: org.eclipse.ui

When pressing the button to create new web app project nothing happens. What can i do?

EDIT:

stack trace:

> org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/platform/shared/ui/IPixelConverter
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
>       at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:850)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:743)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:727)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:662)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
>       at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/platform/shared/ui/IPixelConverter
>       at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.actions.AbstractOpenWizardAction.run(AbstractOpenWizardAction.java:97)
>       at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.actions.NewWebAppToolbarHandler.execute(NewWebAppToolbarHandler.java:27)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
>       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
>       ... 37 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform.shared.ui.IPixelConverter cannot be found by com.google.gdt.eclipse.platform_3.2.3.v201304260926-rel-r42
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 46 more

Comment: See if the .log file in the workspace .metadata contains an error and stack trace

Comment: You can also look in Window->Show View->Error Log. Please post the stack trace.